# Determining loops in circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

For some reason I can't wrap my head around this concept. I find it really hard to find the loops in circuits. This is problem, since I can create all the equations from second Kirchhoff law. Is there any precise algorithm, which I can use to find them. When I'm searching for the loops i'm starting from the top-right element and go to the lowest-left element. But I'm constantly missing loops. I'll give an example of the process which is happening in my head when I'm searching for loops.
Given this circuit:
[image]

1. Start from R1, pass through the whole circuit 1st loop
2. Start from R1, pass through r2 then v2 and r3, 2nd loop
3. Start from R2, pass through R4 then V3 and R5, 3rd loop
4. Start from R3, pass through R6 then R4 4th loop 
   I don't see any other loops on the circuit

Comment: Looks like you found all loops. So what's the question?

Comment: I'm asking if this is the right way to do it. Or a way to determine if this is the correct count.

Comment: More like an aptitude question. No algo n all. Just observe carefully to find all loops.

Comment: I forgot to add the word "Relevant". You got all the relevant loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed some
R6,R4,R2,R1,BACK TO R6
R1,R3,V2,R4,V3,R5,R1

Algorithms for loops are found in graph theory (trees, etc.). You are seeing why node analysis is much easier to set up

Comment: I just want to add this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124463/network-theorem
it gives a way to determine the number of loops in the circuit, based on nodes and branches

Comment: yes, this formula gives you the number of loops, but doesn't tell you where they are. Nevertheless, it gives a good check that you've found them all.

Comment: Been many years since I've taught ckts. The formula

Comment: cut myself off. Forgot formula L = B - N + 1 only gives # of INDEPENDENT loops.